# Python generate exe for python project

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, pyinstaller, executable

I am learning Python and managed to create my first project. Now I have several files and folders in my project folder which I need, to let my program (tkinter based GUI with some selenium code) run correcty.

I have not found a way to convert my main.py file to an .exe file while incuding my complete project folder.

Is there any advice which module I could use to achieve that?

Is ther a way to just pack the complete project and generate a executable "folder" which I can share with friends?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `main.py` kicks off like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # my code
```

then you should be able to call pyinstaller like this:

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

If you have any data files you can add them using the command line or using a spec file. [Here's](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) the docs.